# Query very slow - how to optimize

Tags: mysql, performance, index-tuning, query-performance

I have a query which is taking up to 7 minutes to execute.
My Question is, how am I able to optimize this query?

The EXPLAIN statement shows two bottlenecks which are following:

1. table `fmonatsstatistik` has 1721051 Records
2. table `filialartikel` has 268460 Records

Extra is saying Using sort_union, using where, using, temporary, using filesort which I assume is really bad.

Indexes `filalartikel`:

```
+---------------+------------+----------------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table         | Non_unique | Key_name       | Seq_in_index | Column_name    | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+---------------+------------+----------------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| filialartikel |          0 | PRIMARY        |            1 | FilialNr       | A         |          18 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| filialartikel |          0 | PRIMARY        |            2 | ArtikelNr      | A         |      256176 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| filialartikel |          1 | ArtikelName    |            1 | ArtikelName    | A         |       15029 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| filialartikel |          1 | ArtikelZusatz1 |            1 | ArtikelZusatz1 | A         |         392 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| filialartikel |          1 | ArtikelZusatz2 |            1 | ArtikelZusatz2 | A         |           6 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| filialartikel |          1 | ArtikelZusatz3 |            1 | ArtikelZusatz3 | A         |          44 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| filialartikel |          1 | Matchcode      |            1 | Matchcode      | A         |       12443 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| filialartikel |          1 | RegalStandort  |            1 | RegalStandort  | A         |           1 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| filialartikel |          1 | EinkaugMenge   |            1 | EinkaufMenge   | A         |         232 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| filialartikel |          1 | EinkaufSumme   |            1 | EinkaufSumme   | A         |        1012 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+---------------+------------+----------------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

Indexes `fmonatsstatistik`:

```
+------------------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table            | Non_unique | Key_name   | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+------------------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| fmonatsstatistik |          0 | PRIMARY    |            1 | Jahr        | A         |         432 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| fmonatsstatistik |          0 | PRIMARY    |            2 | Monat       | A         |        3462 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| fmonatsstatistik |          0 | PRIMARY    |            3 | ArtikelNr   | A         |      138994 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| fmonatsstatistik |          0 | PRIMARY    |            4 | FilialNr    | A         |     1257526 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| fmonatsstatistik |          1 | ArtikelNr  |            1 | ArtikelNr   | A         |       14366 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| fmonatsstatistik |          1 | Woche      |            1 | Monat       | A         |          11 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| fmonatsstatistik |          1 | Umsatz     |            1 | Umsatz      | A         |         851 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| fmonatsstatistik |          1 | Betrag     |            1 | Betrag      | A         |        4757 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| fmonatsstatistik |          1 | MWStBetrag |            1 | MWStBetrag  | A         |        7669 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| fmonatsstatistik |          1 | GMEKPreis  |            1 | GMEKPreis   | A         |        2321 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| fmonatsstatistik |          1 | Monat      |            1 | Monat       | A         |          11 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| fmonatsstatistik |          1 | GMVKPreis  |            1 | GMVKPreis   | A         |        2640 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+------------------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

Query:

```
    SELECT fmonatsstatistik.artikelnr,
       filialartikel.artikelname,
       artikel.artikelnummer,
       filialartikel.artikelzusatz1,
       filialartikel.artikelzusatz2,
       filialartikel.artikelzusatz3,
       filialen.filialname,
       (SELECT Concat_ws(' ', name1, name2)
        FROM   adressen
        WHERE  adressnr = (SELECT adressnr
                           FROM   artikellieferanten
                           WHERE  artikellieferanten.artikelnr =
                                  filialartikel.artikelnr
                                  AND artikellieferanten.filialnr =
                                      filialartikel.filialnr
                           ORDER  BY bevorzugt
                           LIMIT  1))                                         AS
       Lieferant,
       (SELECT Sum(filialartikel2.istbestandregal
                   + filialartikel2.istbestandlager)
        FROM   filialartikel AS filialartikel2
        WHERE  filialartikel.artikelnr = filialartikel2.artikelnr
               AND ( filialartikel2.filialnr = 0
                      OR '0' = '0' ))                                         AS
       Bestand,
       Sum(fmonatsstatistik.umsatz)                                           AS
       MengeSumme,
       Sum(fmonatsstatistik.betrag)                                           AS
       BetragSumme,
       Sum(fmonatsstatistik.betrag - fmonatsstatistik.mwstbetrag)             AS
       MWStExclSumme,
       (SELECT warengruppenname
        FROM   warengruppen
        WHERE  warengruppen.warengruppennr = artikel.warengruppennr)          AS
       WgName,
       (SELECT warenobergruppenname
        FROM   warenobergruppen
        WHERE  warenobergruppen.warenobergruppennr = (SELECT warenobergruppennr
                                                      FROM   warengruppen
                                                      WHERE
                       warengruppen.warengruppennr = artikel.warengruppennr)) AS
       WogName,
       filialartikel.regalstandort                                            AS
       RegalPlatz,
       Sum(fmonatsstatistik.betrag - fmonatsstatistik.mwstbetrag) -
Sum(fmonatsstatistik.umsatz) * ( fmonatsstatistik.gmekpreis + 0 ) * (
                                                                    (SELECT
waehrungkurs
                                                                     FROM
waehrungen
                                                                     WHERE
waehrungnr = (SELECT landw�hrung
              FROM   land
              WHERE  landnr = (SELECT landnr
                               FROM   filialen
                               WHERE
filialen.filial_id =
fmonatsstatistik.filialnr))) / (SELECT waehrungkurs
                                FROM   waehrungen
WHERE  waehrungnr = (SELECT waehrungnr
                     FROM   adressen
                     WHERE  adressnr = (SELECT adressnr
                                        FROM   artikellieferanten
                                        WHERE  artikellieferanten.artikelnr =
                                               filialartikel.artikelnr
                                               AND
                                               artikellieferanten.filialnr =
                                               filialartikel.filialnr
                                       LIMIT  1))) + 0 )               AS
       Rohertrag,
Sum(fmonatsstatistik.betrag - fmonatsstatistik.mwstbetrag) -
Sum(fmonatsstatistik.umsatz) * (
IF(filialartikel.einkaufmenge<>0, filialartikel.einkaufsumme/filialartikel.einkaufmenge, fmonatsstatistik.gmekpreis)
  + 0 ) * ( (SELECT waehrungkurs
             FROM   waehrungen
             WHERE  waehrungnr = (SELECT landw�hrung
                                  FROM   land
                                  WHERE  landnr = (SELECT landnr
                                                   FROM   filialen
                                                   WHERE
                        filialen.filial_id =
                        fmonatsstatistik.filialnr))) / (SELECT waehrungkurs
                        FROM   waehrungen
                        WHERE  waehrungnr = (SELECT waehrungnr
                                             FROM   adressen
                                             WHERE
                               adressnr = (SELECT adressnr
                                           FROM   artikellieferanten
                                           WHERE
                               artikellieferanten.artikelnr =
                               filialartikel.artikelnr
                               AND
            artikellieferanten.filialnr =
            filialartikel.filialnr
                                                     LIMIT  1))) + 0 ) AS
Rohertrag3
FROM   fmonatsstatistik
       INNER JOIN filialen
               ON fmonatsstatistik.filialnr = filialen.filial_id
       INNER JOIN filialartikel
               ON filialartikel.artikelnr = fmonatsstatistik.artikelnr
                  AND filialartikel.filialnr = fmonatsstatistik.filialnr
       INNER JOIN artikel
               ON artikel.artikelnr = fmonatsstatistik.artikelnr
WHERE  ( fmonatsstatistik.filialnr = 0
          OR '0' = '0' )
       AND ( artikel.warengruppennr = (SELECT fvalue
                                       FROM   query_params
                                       WHERE  fname = 'WarengruppenNr'
                                       LIMIT  1)
              OR (SELECT fvalue
                  FROM   query_params
                  WHERE  fname = 'WarengruppenNr'
                  LIMIT  1) = 0 )
       AND ( artikel.sortimentnr = (SELECT fvalue
                                    FROM   query_params
                                    WHERE  fname = 'SortimentNr'
                                    LIMIT  1)
              OR (SELECT fvalue
                  FROM   query_params
                  WHERE  fname = 'SortimentNr'
                  LIMIT  1) = 0 )
       AND ( CONVERT(artikel.artikelnummer, CHAR) =
             (SELECT fvalue
              FROM   query_params
              WHERE  fname = 'Artikelnummer'
              LIMIT  1)
              OR (SELECT fvalue
                  FROM   query_params
                  WHERE  fname = 'Artikelnummer'
                  LIMIT  1) = '' )
       AND ( (SELECT warenobergruppennr
              FROM   warengruppen
              WHERE  warengruppen.warengruppennr = artikel.warengruppennr) =
                   (SELECT fvalue
                    FROM
                   query_params
                   WHERE
                   fname
                   =
                   'WarenObergruppenNr'
                   LIMIT  1)
              OR (SELECT fvalue
                  FROM   query_params
                  WHERE  fname = 'WarenObergruppenNr'
                  LIMIT  1) = 0 )
       AND fmonatsstatistik.jahr * 12 + fmonatsstatistik.monat >= 24193
       AND fmonatsstatistik.jahr * 12 + fmonatsstatistik.monat <= 24204
       AND ( CONVERT(filialartikel.regalstandort, CHAR) =
             (SELECT fvalue
              FROM   query_params
              WHERE  fname = 'RegalStandort'
              LIMIT  1)
              OR (SELECT fvalue
                  FROM   query_params
                  WHERE  fname = 'RegalStandort'
                  LIMIT  1) = '' )
       AND ( CONVERT(filialartikel.artikelname, CHAR) LIKE Concat('%',
                   (SELECT fvalue
                          FROM   query_params
                          WHERE  fname = 'ArtikelName'
                          LIMIT  1), '%')
              OR (SELECT fvalue
                  FROM   query_params
                  WHERE  fname = 'ArtikelName'
                  LIMIT  1) = '' )
       AND ( CONVERT(filialartikel.artikelzusatz1, CHAR) LIKE
                   Concat('%', (SELECT fvalue
                          FROM   query_params
                          WHERE  fname = 'ArtikelZusatz1'
                          LIMIT  1), '%')
              OR (SELECT fvalue
                  FROM   query_params
                  WHERE  fname = 'ArtikelZusatz1'
                  LIMIT  1) = '' )
       AND ( CONVERT(filialartikel.artikelzusatz2, CHAR) LIKE
                   Concat('%', (SELECT fvalue
                          FROM   query_params
                          WHERE  fname = 'ArtikelZusatz2'
                          LIMIT  1), '%')
              OR (SELECT fvalue
                  FROM   query_params
                  WHERE  fname = 'ArtikelZusatz2'
                  LIMIT  1) = '' )
       AND ( CONVERT(filialartikel.artikelzusatz3, CHAR) LIKE
                   Concat('%', (SELECT fvalue
                          FROM   query_params
                          WHERE  fname = 'ArtikelZusatz3'
                          LIMIT  1), '%')
              OR (SELECT fvalue
                  FROM   query_params
                  WHERE  fname = 'ArtikelZusatz3'
                  LIMIT  1) = '' )
       AND ( NOT Isnull((SELECT artikelnr
                         FROM   artikellieferanten
                         WHERE  adressnr = (SELECT fvalue
                                            FROM   query_params
                                            WHERE  fname = 'Lieferant'
                                            LIMIT  1)
                                AND
artikellieferanten.artikelnr = artikel.artikelnr
                                AND artikellieferanten.filialnr =
                                    fmonatsstatistik.filialnr
                         ORDER  BY bevorzugt
                         LIMIT  1))
              OR (SELECT fvalue
                  FROM   query_params
                  WHERE  fname = 'Lieferant'
                  LIMIT  1) = '' )
       AND ( umsatz != 0
              OR betrag != 0 )
GROUP  BY fmonatsstatistik.artikelnr,
          filialartikel.artikelname,
          Coalesce(filialartikel.artikelzusatz1, ''),
          Coalesce(filialartikel.artikelzusatz2, ''),
          Coalesce(filialartikel.artikelzusatz3, '')
ORDER  BY wogname ASC,
          wgname ASC,
          artikelname
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't even consider this way of building queries.  Yes, it is clever to disable various `ANDs` by looking up a config value; but it is hideously slow.

Instead, fetch the config values, *then* build the query.  In the process, leave out any `AND` that you can see will evaluate to `TRUE`:

```
AND ( ( ... ) OR ( SELECT fvalue ... ) = '' )
```

That is, fetch the `query_params` to decide the value of that `SELECT`, then either include this in the `WHERE` (if `!=''`) or include it:

```
AND ( ... )
```

After you have fixed most of that, then dig into the `SELECT` clauses.  This, for example, is costly; try to find a way that does not involve nested `SELECTs`:

```
              (  SELECT  waehrungkurs
                    FROM  waehrungen
                    WHERE  waehrungnr = 
                    (   SELECT  landw�hrung
                            FROM  land
                            WHERE  landnr = 
                            (   SELECT  landnr
                                    FROM  filialen
                                    WHERE  filialen.filial_id = fmonatsstatistik.filialnr))
              )
```

Start by turning that into a 3-table `JOIN`.  But you should try to make it even simpler, since there are so many like that.

"filesort" is not "really bad".  In fact you must have at least 2 of them -- one for `GROUP BY` and one for `ORDER BY`.  (`EXPLAIN` fails to say how many are needed.)

Please provide the `EXPLAIN`; the number of `Rows` is often informative.

Comment: Thanks for you answert. I found a missing Index on table filialartikel. I've added a new one (ArtikelNr) as the one that was already existing was combined with filialnr. This speeded up the query from 7min to 0.5sec~

Comment: I see duplicate indexes.  I see indexes on flags -- usually will be ignored.  I don't see any composite indexes (other than the PKs); they often help.  So, further improvements may be possible.